# Get value with javascript from a tag inside a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to extract data from such code:

```
<div class="rateCalc_InfoLine2">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">
        Text1 - <b><font color="red" size="2">$ 500</font></b>;
        Text2 - <b><font color="red">$ 30</font></b>
    </span>
</div>
```

So basically, I need to find the value `30` that is inside the `2nd font tag` of the `span tag` that is inside `div tag` with the class `rateCalc_InfoLine2`. The structure is static, so I dont need to worry about mistakes ( only the value `30` will change )

I know hoe to get the value of the div like this:

```
$(".rateCalc_InfoLine2").html();
```

but how to get the specific one I need?

---

Answer: `$(".rateCalc_InfoLine2 font").eq(1).html().replace('$ ', '');`

Comment: try `$('div.rateCalc_InfoLine2 span font:last').html()`

Comment: This is the basic functionality of jQuery. A single look in the docs could have told you the solution.

Comment: I tried adding more tags to the end, but I didn't notice I can just add them inside the 1st request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first find the font elements within `div` using [**descendant selector**](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and then use index to find the second element using [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/bTxr2/)**

```
$(".rateCalc_InfoLine2 font").eq(1).html();
```

Edit to remove the $

```
strResult = $(".rateCalc_InfoLine2 font").eq(1).html().replace('$ ', '');
```

Comment: www.jsfiddle.net is not working on my system since many days. :( HTML panel is blank and disabled

Comment: There could be problem for missing latest js/resource files. Press ctrl+f5 two three times and try again. Tell me if jsfiddle works?

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I updated my question with the final script ( needed to remove the `$ ` also).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".rateCalc_InfoLine2 font:eq(1)").html();
```

or

```
$(".rateCalc_InfoLine2 font:last").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this specific scenario you could do this:

```
$(".rateCalc_InfoLine2 font")[1].innerHTML;
```

Comment: I doubt if DOM element has `html()` method.

Comment: @VisioN - Oh how silly of me, I forgot that using the `[]` indexers will convert it to an HTML Element

Answer (score 0):

To select the value from inside a tag you need to use `html()`

```
var value = $(".rateCalc_InfoLine2 font").eq(1).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$(".rateCalc_InfoLine2 font")[1].innerHTML;
```

### [Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fudfb/)

Answer (score 0):

The following would [select the relevant element](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/), access its textual content with the `text()` method, `match()` any numeric value inside it, and assign it to `sum`:

```
var price = $('.rateCalc_InfoLine2 font:eq(1)').text().match(/\d{1,}/);
if (price) { var sum = price[0]; }
```

In your example, `sum` would be assigned the value `30`.